# Consulta en kibana combinando un query y determinar un tiempo de muestra

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, kibana

Tengo la siguiente consulta en dev tools en Kibana que me funciona bien, sin determinar un tiempo de busqueda.

```
GET /custom-aliados*/_count
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query" : "(API002) AND (operation)"
                }
       }
}
```

Ahora quiero que hacer esta consulta dentro de un tiempo especifico pero no he podido.

intento esto y con algunas modificaciones pero no me funciona.

```
GET /custom-aliados*/_count
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query" : "(API002) AND (operation)"
           },
              "range" : {
                "gte": "2019-09-16 00:00:00", 
                "lte": "now", 
                "time_zone": "+01:00"
                        }
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que debería ser usando `bool`, dentro se puede usar `must`,`should`, y [algunos mas](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), en este caso usando `must`:

```
GET /custom-aliados*/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "(API002) AND (operation)"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "el_campo_date": {
              "gt": "2019-09-16",
              "lte": "now/d",
              "time_zone": "+01:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

El `range` debe ser especificando el campo (Hay que reemplazar el campo `el_campo_date` por el que corresponda, obviamente.).